# Custom Download Link

Tags: url-rewriting

How can I set up wordpress to recognize

```
www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/history.pdf
```

as something like

```
www.example.com/about/pdf-download/
```

I also want the user not to see the actual link but the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you just need to redirect that one specific request (for /wp-content/uploads/2010/12/history.pdf to /about/history.pdf)?  Or do you need to to handle many requests (say, for /wp-content/uploads/2010/12/* to /about/*)?

If it's the former, use a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or, if you're not on Unix/Linux/BSD, whatever equivalent your OS offers).  If it's the latter, use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) (or, if you're not using Apache, whatever equivalent your Web server offers).

Comment: I'd go one step further and say if it's the latter, use WordPress' Rewrite API instead of mod_rewrite - http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with the methods jalefkowit suggested (due to lack of familiarity, not because they're not a good way to accomplish this!), you might want to take a look at the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin.

Comment: I set up a redirection with pass-through(masquerade one URL as another). When I access the new link there seems to be a problem with headers as the pdf file is coming out like: %PDF-1.4 %äüöß 2 0 obj << /Length 3 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream x��]�n$����Pgn'�[00��J>�݀?�`xx.��Β� �/�e0�$��ڞ�J&�X_,��~��?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is coming out like". Do you mean when you click the link, you're redirected to a page with those characters on it?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i mean